# Writing files in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I want to read and write data from a Text file in windows phone 8 application.
I tried this code

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("File.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isf));
wr.WriteLineAsync("Hello");
wr.Close();
```

But it does nothing.
Please help me out of this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you `await wr.WriteLineAsync("Hello");`? My guess is that you don't see anything because you close your streamwriter before anything's written.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166253/windows-phone-8-choose-text-file-c-sharp/27168118#27168118  it been answered a number of times by many people.

Comment: I think you have to google it first. There are so many helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly read and write a file using Windows.Storage on Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623189/how-to-properly-read-and-write-a-file-using-windows-storage-on-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write data to file:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

//create new file
using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
{
   string someTextData = "This is some text data to be saved in a new text file in the IsolatedStorage!";
   writeFile.WriteLine(someTextData);
   writeFile.Close();
}
```

Read data from file:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{    
     //Visualize the text data in a TextBlock text
     this.text.Text = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Go through this links: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files

https://www.google.co.in/#q=wp8+isolated+storage+geek

Comment: This is great. But still one problem exists
When i double click on the text file> still it is not updated.